# Regex excluding square brackets

Tags: java, regex

I am new to regex. I have this regex:

```
\[(.*[^(\]|\[)].*)\]
```

Basically it should take this:

```
[[a][b][[c]]]
```

And be able to replace with:

```
[dd[d]]
```

abc, d are unrelated.  Needless to say the regex bit isn't working. it replaces the entire string with "d" in this case.

Any explanation or aid would be great!

EDIT:

I tried another regex,

```
\[([^\]]{0})\]
```

This one worked for the case where brackets contain no inner brackets and nothing else inside. But it doesn't work for the described case.

Comment: Try removing `.*` from your first regex.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't believe that changed anything for me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to know that `.` dot is special character which represents "any character beside new line mark" and `*` is greedy so it will try to find maximal match.

In your regex `\[(.*[^(\]|\[)].*)\]` first `.*` will represent maximal set of characters between `[` and `[^(\]|\[)].*)\]]` and this part can be understood as non `[` or `]` character, optional other characters `.*` and finally `]`. So this regex will match your entire input.

---

To get rid of that problem remove both `.*` from your regex. Also you don't need to use `|` or `(` `)` inside `[^...]`.

```
System.out.println("[[a][b][[c]]]".replaceAll("\\[[^\\]\\[]\\]", "d"));
```

Output: `[dd[d]]`

Answer (score 1):

`\[(\[a\])(\[b\])\[(\[c\])\]\]`

If you need to double backslashes in the current context (such as you are placing it in a "" style string):

`\\[(\\[a\\])(\\[b\\])\\[(\\[c\\])\\]\\]`

An example replacement for `a`, `b` and `c` is `[^\]]*`, or if you need to escape backslashes `[^\\]]*`.

Now you can replace capture one, capture two and capture three each with `d`.

---

If the string you are replacing in is not exactly of that format, then you want to do a global replacement with

`(\[a\])`

replacing `a`,

`(\[[^\]]*\])`

doubling backslashes,

`(\\[[^\\]]*\\])`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
System.out.println("[[a][b][[c]]]".replaceAll("\\[[^]\\[]]", "d"));
```

if a,b,c are in real world more than one character, use this:

```
System.out.println("[[a][b][[c]]]".replaceAll("\\[[^]\\[]++]", "d"));
```

The idea is to use a character class that contains all characters but `[` and `]`. The class is: `[^]\\[]` and other square brackets in the pattern are literals.

Note that a literal closing square bracket don't need to be escaped at the first position in a character class and outside a character class.